# Python: Automatically update the output

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and I actually using my free time to learn Python myself. Currently I am working on a python project that will be use to calculate some engineering solution.

Basically the user need to key in a lot parameter. But the program will first fill up all parameter using typical/standard parameter for user for the very first time. But not all parameter will be needed, depend what solution the user need.

So, summary is:

1. I have a def function that call python to do calculation based on this set of calculation rule, which is **def Menu()**
2. Under this calculation rule there are several method which require different parameter, therefore, I set *RequireWidth*(and etc) to be **False** at the first place then only made it **True** if this parameter is require. Entry box will shows and user can fill in the parameter. By the end of this, python should have all the necessary parameter.

> For example, the analysis of Element A need 4 parameters and Analysis
> of Element B require 6 parameters.

3. I then call again another def called **def CalTensionSteelArea(D1_Coordinate_Y)** function to calculate the output, because in other rules of calculation, this set of calculation may be not necessary.

> For example, Element A with 4 parameters require 2 calculations(i.e tension steel area required and Weight induced) and Element B require 3 different calculation.

So my question is

1. How can we do so that when the user change the parameter, python can automatically update the output? I try trace but what i get is *'Entry' object has no attribute 'trace'*
2. In the every entry for the user, if the user type 250, can we do so that it can automatically change to it to 250.0 after user deselect the entry box?
3. Is it possible for user to go to the next entry box by pressing down or left/right button?
4. Any idea to simplified these? I still new to python and are still exploring it.

I am sorry the code below is very long and but my intention is to let everyone who wanted to help to guide me to fully understand what is happening here.

```
from math import sqrt, pi, tan, atan, sin, asin, cos, radians, degrees
from tkinter import *
import ctypes

global D1_Coordinate_Y
global UltMomentX
global b, depth, length, yc, ys
global fck, fyk, fyw, cover, MinClearSpacing, MinSteel, landa, XoverL
global ParameterInput


def Menu():
    ## GUI PARAMETER
    Bg_Colour = 'White'
    Prm_Colour = '#fffecc'
    Scd_Colour = 'White'

    ## DEFAULT VALUE
    RequireWidth = False
    RequireDepth = False
    RequireLength = False
    RequireSafetySteel = False
    RequireSafetyConcrete = False
    RequireAccBendingShear = False

    RequireConcreteStrength = False
    RequireSteelStrength = False
    RequireLinkStrength = False
    RequireClearSpacing = False
    RequireCover = False
    RequireMinSteel = False
    RequireLanda = False
    Require_XoverL_limit = False

    RequireMoment = False
    RequireShear = False
    RequireTorsion = False
    RequireLoadFactor = True
    RequireUltMoment = True
    RequireUltShear = True
    RequireUltTorsion = True
    RequireCheck = True

    ReqTensionSteelArea = False

    Display = Tk()
    Display.title('Cedesign')
    Display.geometry("1920x1080")
    TkScale = 1.3
    Display.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', TkScale)
    Display.config(bg=Bg_Colour)
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

    # C1/3/5 are Parameter description for user
    C1_Coordinate_X = 140  # Coordinate of Column 1 in terms of X (Left-right) direction
    C3_Coordinate_X = 360  #
    C5_Coordinate_X = 620
    C1_Coordinate_Y = 10  # Coordinate of Row 1 in terms of Y (up-down) direction
    C3_Coordinate_Y = 10
    C5_Coordinate_Y = 10

    # C2/4/6 are Parameter input box for user
    C1_C2_Distance = 0
    C3_C4_Distance = 0
    C5_C6_Distance = 0
    C2_Box_Width = 6
    C4_Box_Width = 6
    C6_Box_Width = 6
    C1_C2a_Distance = C1_C2_Distance + C2_Box_Width * 7.6
    C3_C4a_Distance = C3_C4_Distance + C4_Box_Width * 7.6
    C5_C6a_Distance = C5_C6_Distance + C6_Box_Width * 7.6
    R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment = TkScale * 13.5  # Row 1 Increment of each cell downward after each successive display
    R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment = TkScale * 13.5  # Row 3 Increment of each cell downward after each successive display
    R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment = TkScale * 13.5  # Row 5 Increment of each cell downward after each successive display
    PrimaryParameterBorderWidth = 1
    SecondaryParameterBorderWidth = 1

    # DESIGN PARAMETER
    Code = "EC"
    Design = "Beam"

    def PrintCalculation():
        PrintButton = Label(Display, text=width.get())
        PrintButton.place(x=500, y=500)

    if Design == "Beam":
        RequireWidth = True
        RequireDepth = True
        RequireLength = True
        RequireSafetySteel = True
        RequireSafetyConcrete = True
        RequireAccBendingShear = True

        RequireConcreteStrength = True
        RequireSteelStrength = True
        RequireLinkStrength = True
        RequireClearSpacing = True
        RequireCover = True
        RequireMinSteel = True
        RequireLanda = True
        Require_XoverL_limit = True

        RequireMoment = True
        RequireShear = True
        RequireTorsion = True
        ReqTensionSteelArea = True

    if RequireWidth:
        Label(Display, text="width", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X, y=C1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C2_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, float(250))
        width = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="mm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2a_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
    C1_Coordinate_Y += R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireDepth:
        Label(Display, text="d", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X, y=C1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C2_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 600)
        depth = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="mm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2a_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
    C1_Coordinate_Y += R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireLength:
        Label(Display, text="Length", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X, y=C1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C2_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 5000)
        length = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="mm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2a_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
        C1_Coordinate_Y += R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment
    C1_Coordinate_Y += R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    # Empty
    C1_Coordinate_Y += R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireSafetySteel:
        Label(Display, text="\u03B3s", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X, y=C1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C2_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 1.15)
        ys = float(ParameterInput.get())
    C1_Coordinate_Y += R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireSafetyConcrete:
        Label(Display, text="\u03B3c", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X, y=C1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C2_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 1.5)
        yc = float(ParameterInput.get())
    C1_Coordinate_Y += R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireAccBendingShear:
        text_dis = "acc-bending/shear" if Code == "EC" else "ym" if Code == "BS" else "unknown"
        Label(Display, text=text_dis, bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C1_Coordinate_X, y=C1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C2_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 0.85 if Code == "EC" else 1.25 if Code == "BS" else 1.0)
        if Code == "EC":
            acc_moment = float(ParameterInput.get())
            ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C2_Box_Width, justify='right',
                                   borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                                   bg=Scd_Colour)
            ParameterInput.place(x=C1_Coordinate_X + C1_C2a_Distance, y=C1_Coordinate_Y)
            ParameterInput.insert(0, 1.0)
            acc_shear = float(ParameterInput.get())
        else:
            ym = float(ParameterInput.get())
    C1_Coordinate_Y += R1_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireConcreteStrength:
        Label(Display, text="fcu", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X, y=C3_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C4_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 25)
        fck = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="N/mm2", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4a_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
    C3_Coordinate_Y += R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireSteelStrength:
        Label(Display, text="fyk", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X, y=C3_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C4_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 460)
        fyk = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="N/mm2", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4a_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
    C3_Coordinate_Y += R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireLinkStrength:
        Label(Display, text="fyw", anchor="e", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X, y=C3_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C4_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 250)
        fyw = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="N/mm2", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4a_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
    C3_Coordinate_Y += R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireClearSpacing:
        Label(Display, text="Min clear spacing", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X, y=C3_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C4_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 50)
        Label(Display, text="mm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4a_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        MinClearSpacing = float(ParameterInput.get())
    C3_Coordinate_Y += R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireCover:
        Label(Display, text="Cover", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X, y=C3_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C4_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 25)
        cover = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="mm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4a_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
    C3_Coordinate_Y += R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireMinSteel:
        Label(Display, text="Min % of Steel", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X, y=C3_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C4_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 0.13)
        MinSteel = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="%", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4a_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
    C3_Coordinate_Y += R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireLanda:
        Label(Display, text="Landa", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X, y=C3_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C4_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 0.80)
        landa = float(ParameterInput.get())
    C3_Coordinate_Y += R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if Require_XoverL_limit:
        Label(Display, text="X/L Limit", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C3_Coordinate_X, y=C3_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C4_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C3_Coordinate_X + C3_C4_Distance, y=C3_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, 0.45)
        XoverL = float(ParameterInput.get())
    C3_Coordinate_Y += R3_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireMoment:
        Label(Display, text="Un-factored Moment", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X, y=C5_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C6_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, float(150))
        MomentX = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="kNm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6a_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
    C5_Coordinate_Y += R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireShear:
        Label(Display, text="Un-factored Shear", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X, y=C5_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C6_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, float(500))
        ShearX = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="kN", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6a_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
    C5_Coordinate_Y += R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireTorsion:
        Label(Display, text="Un-factored Torsion", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X, y=C5_Coordinate_Y,
                                                                       anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C6_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, float(20))
        Torsion = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="kNm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6a_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
    C5_Coordinate_Y += R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireLoadFactor:
        Label(Display, text="Load Factor", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X, y=C5_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C6_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=PrimaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Prm_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, float(1.5))
        LoadFactor = float(ParameterInput.get())
    C5_Coordinate_Y += R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireUltMoment:
        Label(Display, text="Factored Moment", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X, y=C5_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C6_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, MomentX * LoadFactor)
        UltMomentX = float(ParameterInput.get()) * 1e6
        Label(Display, text="kNm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6a_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
    C5_Coordinate_Y += R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireUltShear:
        Label(Display, text="Factored Shear", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X, y=C5_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C6_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, ShearX * LoadFactor)
        UltShearX = float(ParameterInput.get()) * 1e3
        Label(Display, text="kN", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6a_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
    C5_Coordinate_Y += R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireUltTorsion:
        Label(Display, text="Factored Torsion", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X, y=C5_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C6_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, Torsion * LoadFactor)
        UltTorsion = float(ParameterInput.get())
        Label(Display, text="kNm", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6a_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
    C5_Coordinate_Y += R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    if RequireCheck:
        Label(Display, text="TEXT", bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=C5_Coordinate_X, y=C5_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
        ParameterInput = Entry(Display, width=C6_Box_Width, justify='right', borderwidth=SecondaryParameterBorderWidth,
                               bg=Scd_Colour)
        ParameterInput.place(x=C5_Coordinate_X + C5_C6_Distance, y=C5_Coordinate_Y)
        ParameterInput.insert(0, acc_moment if Code == "EC" else ym if Code == "BS" else 66)
        UltTorsion = float(ParameterInput.get())
    C5_Coordinate_Y += R5_Coordinate_Y_Increment

    D1_Coordinate_X = 150
    D1_Coordinate_Y = max(C1_Coordinate_Y, C3_Coordinate_Y, C5_Coordinate_Y) + 25

    DR1_Coordinate_Y_Increment = TkScale * 13.7  # Row 1 Increment of each cell downward after each successive display
    DR3_Coordinate_Y_Increment = TkScale * 13.7  # Row 3 Increment of each cell downward after each successive display
    DR5_Coordinate_Y_Increment = TkScale * 13.7  # Row 5 Increment of each cell downward after each successive display

    D1_D2_Distance = 0
    D2_D3_Distance = 180
    D3_D4_Distance = 0
    D2_Coordinate_X = D1_Coordinate_X + D1_D2_Distance
    D3_Coordinate_X = D2_Coordinate_X + D2_D3_Distance
    D4_Coordinate_X = D3_Coordinate_X + D3_D4_Distance

    MainBarDiameter = 20
    MainBarSpacing = 125
    LinkDiameter = 10
    LinkRebarArea = pi * 10 ** 2 / 4
    NumberOfLeg = 2

    def CalTensionSteelArea(D1_Coordinate_Y):

        d = depth - cover - LinkDiameter - 0.5 * MainBarDiameter
        K = UltMomentX / (fck * width * (d ** 2))
        K_prime = round(acc_moment / yc * landa * XoverL - ((acc_moment / yc) * landa * 0.4 * (XoverL ** 2)), 3)
        # MomentKf = acc_moment * 2 / yc
        LevelArm = round(min(0.5 + sqrt(0.25 - K if K < K_prime else K_prime / K_prime), 0.95), 3)
        print(LevelArm)
        AsRequired = round(UltMomentX / ((1 / ys) * fyk * LevelArm * d), 1)
        AsMin = MinSteel / 100 * width * depth
        AsProvided = (pi / 4 * 20 ** 2) / (MainBarSpacing / 1000)  # Default mm2

        def Output_D(D1_text, D2_text, D3_text, D4_Text):
            Label(Display, text=D1_text, bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=D1_Coordinate_X, y=D1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
            Label(Display, text=D2_text, bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=D2_Coordinate_X, y=D1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='nw')
            Label(Display, text=D3_text, bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=D3_Coordinate_X, y=D1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='ne')
            Label(Display, text=D4_Text, bg=Bg_Colour).place(x=D4_Coordinate_X, y=D1_Coordinate_Y, anchor='nw')

        D4_Desc_Depth = (str(depth) + " - " + str(cover) + " - " + str(LinkDiameter) + " - (0.5x" +
                         str(MainBarDiameter) + ")")
        D4_Desc_K = (str(UltMomentX) + " / (" + str(fck) + " * " + str(width) + " x (" + str(d) + "^2)")
        D4_Desc_K_prime = (str(acc_moment) + "/" + str(yc) + "x" + str(landa) + "x" + str(XoverL) + " - (" + str(
            acc_moment) + "/" + str(yc) + ")x" + str(landa) + "x" + str(0.4) + "x(" + str(XoverL) + "^2))")
        D4_Desc_LevelArm = "Min of {" + \
                           "0.5 + sqrt(0.25 " + "- " + str(K if K < K_prime else K_prime) + " / " + str(
            K_prime) + "} or {0.95}"
        D4_Desc_Asreq = str(UltMomentX) + " / " + str(ys) + " x " + str(fyk) + " x " + str(LevelArm) + " x " + str(d)
        D4_Desc_Asmin = str(MinSteel) + "x" + str(width) + " x " + str(depth) + " /100"

        Output_D("Effective depth, d =", (str(d) + " mm"), "d = ", D4_Desc_Depth)
        D1_Coordinate_Y += DR1_Coordinate_Y_Increment
        Output_D("K =", round(K, 3), "K = ", D4_Desc_K)
        D1_Coordinate_Y += DR1_Coordinate_Y_Increment
        Output_D("K' =", round(K_prime, 3), "K' = ", D4_Desc_K_prime)
        D1_Coordinate_Y += DR1_Coordinate_Y_Increment
        Output_D("level arm, z =", str(LevelArm) + " d", "z = ", D4_Desc_LevelArm)
        D1_Coordinate_Y += DR1_Coordinate_Y_Increment
        Output_D("As.require =", str(AsRequired) + " mm2", "As.req = ", D4_Desc_Asreq)
        D1_Coordinate_Y += DR1_Coordinate_Y_Increment
        Output_D("As.min =", str(AsMin) + " mm2", "As.min = ", D4_Desc_Asmin)

        return D1_Coordinate_Y

    if ReqTensionSteelArea:
        CalTensionSteelArea(D1_Coordinate_Y)

    Display.mainloop()

Menu()
```

Comment: I tried reading through your code. I really tried but I feel it is very disorganized. You have function inside function and your explanation is also not very clear. Can you change it in a way that is easier to understand?

Comment: Plus, this is a Windows specific code so I cannot execute it either